# NumberFormatException is throw on parsing a integer

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I am getting the following exception when i get execute the following code

```
Integer.parseInt(1357679682162)+1

 INFO | jvm 1 | srvmain | 2013/01/08 22:22:09.496 | Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1357679682162"
 INFO | jvm 1 | srvmain | 2013/01/08 22:22:09.496 | at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 INFO | jvm 1 | srvmain | 2013/01/08 22:22:09.496 | at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 INFO | jvm 1 | srvmain | 2013/01/08 22:22:09.496 | at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What is the actual code? `1357679682162` is not a `String`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number you are passing is outside the range of integer which is from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

Answer (score 3):

That number is too big for integer. Integer is 32 bit value, so max value is 2,147,483,647. Try using long instead.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Long.parseLong(1357679682162);
```

Answer (score 0):

Java Integer Max value is 2147483647.

And you are trying to parse 1357679682162.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the number too big to fit in an int? The range of int in java is from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. Maybe you should use parseLong instead.

try

```
Long.parseLong(1357679682162)+1
```

Answer (score 0):

The number is too long.

Integer is supposed to be less than 2 ^31 = 2147483646

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Answer (score 0):

Check yourself with below code and use the feasible type for your solution.

```
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
System.out.println(Long.MAX_VALUE);
```